# Outlook change reply header format ("sent by", etc.)

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When replying or forwarding a message Outlook has the default format:

```
    -----Original Message-----
From: Someone <someone@someplace.com> 
Sent: Date
To: Me <foo@bar.com>
Subject: Outlook formatting
```

I wish to customize these fields, e.g. changing `From:` to `Sender:`. How can I do this in Outlook?

Comment: In case you know Visual Basic for Applications, you can start with [QuoteFixMacro](https://github.com/macros4outlook/quotefixmacro) and modify the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, it is all by design and we could not change From to Sender. Outlook seems have no options for us to change that.